# How can the amplitude of the same acoustic wave be different in a interferometer?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics, interference, power

I came up with an exercise on Halliday Resnick Krane that asked a question which consfuses me. I premit that I do not look for a solution of the exercise but for suggestions only regarding the highlighted part.

[image]

> Consider the acoustic interferometer in the picture. The lenght SAD is fixed, while SBD can be
>   changed. A sound is produced in S and detected in D. We know that for
>   a certain position of B a minimum of intensity of $10\mu W/cm^2$ is detected in  D, and if we move B of a quantity $\Delta s=1.65m$  a
>   maximum on intensity of $90\mu W/cm^2$ is detected in D. Find the amplitudes of the
>   waves that arrives in D. **How can you explain that these aplitudes
>   are different even if the waves were generated by the same source?**

Indeed I find that $\frac{A_1}{A_2}=2$.

Is it correct to say that the differce in amplitude of the two single waves generated by the same source is due to the fact that the wave-fronts are (even if it is not specified in the text) **spherical**, hence $A\propto \frac{1}{r}$? Therefore a longer path covered implies a smaller amplitude?